# Stored Proceedure that returns a boolean?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm new to SQL but I'm trying to minimize code duplication. I am working on a game whose sever will use MySQL C++ connector. I will also host a website that will access the same database. They both need to authenticate users. Ideally, I want to write a stored procedure that takes in a username and a hash, then returns a boolean if the name/password match.

I'm not too bad at writing queries, but stored proceedures are new territory.

Could someone give me a simple MySQL stored procedure example using a dummy table like this:

```
Table Player
Column PlayerID (int, primary key, not null, auto increment)
Column PlayerUsername (varchar 25, not null)
Column PlayerPassword (varchar 25, not null)
```

How I might create a stored procedure that takes in a name and password, and returns true if there is at least 1 record where the username and password match the parameter one.

Once I see the syntax for stored procedures I should be able to create my own. My needs are pretty basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS MY_FUNCTION//

create function MY_FUNCTION(name varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8, 
                            pwd varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8, )
RETURNS tinyint(1)
READS SQL DATA SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    declare result tinyint(1);

    SELECT if(count(*)>0,1,0) INTO result 
    FROM users
    WHERE users.name=name and users.pwd=pwd;

    RETURN result;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```